# Xamarin How to select uitableview cell programatically based on defaultsettings

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've seen a few examples of a uitableview and loading data, but i cant find a solution that i need.

basically i have a data source (myList) which i load data into in the UIViewController

```
public class Lookup
{

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public List<Lookup> myList = new List<Lookup>();
```

Once I've loaded data from the web service I bind the data to the tableview, which works fine....

```
myTableView.Source = new tableSource(MyList, this);
```

this is a sample from the source....

```
   class tableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    List<HospitalLookup> TableItems;
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";
    UIVCPreferences Parent;

    public tableSitesSource(List<Lookup> items, UIVCPreferences parent) 
    {
        TableItems = items;
        Parent = parent;
    }
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        Lookup item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];            
        if (cell == null)
        { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }
        cell.TextLabel.Text = item.Name;...
```

I'm trying to find a way of selecting a table value based on a preference value the user has, lets say UserLookupValue = 5.

i've seen scrolltorow but i dont know how to get find the index based on the datasource id or name. I've tried something like:

```
       myTableView.SelectRow(List.Find(UserLookupValue),false,UITableViewScrollPosition.None);
```

I'm guessing i may need another way of doing this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At First: Your code is hard to read. You should improve it by sticking to the general naming convention for c#.

What is `List` in `myTableView.SelectRow(...)`? If it is of type `List<LookUp>` it should by `myList`. Also `SelectRow` needs a NSIndexPath as first parameter but `List.Find` will return a Lookup instance. Try the following by replacing

```
myTableView.SelectRow(List.Find(UserLookupValue),false,UITableViewScrollPosition.None);
```

with

```
var userLookupValueIndex = myList.IndexOf(userLookupValue);    
myTableView.SelectRow(NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(userLookupIndex, 0), false, UITableViewScrollPosition.None);
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. Sorry about the naming convention, i had to hack some of my code to give the example. I'll pay more attention to this in future.